# Twitter saved JSON String to Java Object (POJO) using something like twitter4j..?

Tags: java, json, twitter, gson, twitter4j

I have a large collection of twitter messages from the streaming twitter API saved as JSON strings in text files.

I wanted to know if anyone knew how I could convert these JSON strings into something like the Twitter4J status object for use as a simple object with getters and setters?

I was thinking about debugging the source and writing my own inject class which would mimic the input stream classes, however I wonder if there is a better way..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try DataObjectFactory#createStatus(String). It's a simple static method that returns one single twitter4j.Status object.
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/json/DataObjectFactory.html#createStatus(java.lang.String)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks heaps, Love your work with Twitter4J, keep it up!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Google's Protobuff or Codehause's XStream or Jackson

This thread might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the data. One thought that comes to mind is importing it into a database like MongoDb which already has support for importing JSON http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools . then you can proceed to analyse or convert the data further from there

Comment: Hey, yeah good idea, already done this one... The problem is that the import tool can only handle Json arrays (i.e. nested object files) up to 4MB.... I have over 400GB of messages to process... Dont really want to have to split it out to 100,000+ files... Any other ideas on how i could import this data?